# Using conanfile.txt and conanfile.py in the same directory

Tags: c++, build, package-managers, conan

I have a C++ library that I build using Conan. It has a `conanfile.txt` with some dependencies and options. I build it using `conan install ...` to build thirdparty libraries and create conan config, and then using `cmake` to build the library itself.

Now I want to make the library itself a conan package. I've added `conanfile.py`, but now I can't build the library the way I did before because conan will use `conanfile.py` and ignore `conanfile.txt`.

How should I approach to solving this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default Conan prefers *conanfile.py*, but you can use any name that you want.

To use a specific file you need to pass the file name:

```
conan install ../conanfile.txt
```